# Minimized Application with TTaskbar Screws Explorer Navigation Bar and Copy Paste

Tags: windows, delphi, taskbar, minimize

**Delphi 10.4.2**

I have a software which starts minimized :

```
const
  WM_DELAYED_MINIMISE = WM_USER + 300;

procedure TMain.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(self.Handle,WM_DELAYED_MINIMISE,0,0);
end;

procedure TMain.DelayedMinimise(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  Main.WindowState:=TWindowState.wsMinimized;

  Timer1.Enabled:=true;
end;
```

I also have a TTaskBar on the Form configured like this :

ProgressState:=Normal

whenever I do something I update the TTaskBar like this :

```
barTask.ProgressValue:=0;
barTask.ProgressMaxValue:=pbStatus.Max;

pbStatus.Position:=i;
barTask.ProgressValue:=pbStatus.Position;
Application.ProcessMessages;
```

This works but after a while ( quiet a few days ) on both Windows 2012 and Windows 10 the Explorer
Navbar gets totally screwed up . Copy paste is also no longer working .

Explorer:
[image: Explorer]

Total Commander:
[image: Total Commander]

What am I doing wrong here ?

Thank you.

Comment: What is `pbStatus` in your sample code? And when and how are you manipulating it?

Comment: What makes you think you are the one responsble for Explorer getting "totally screwed up"?

Comment: @RemyLebeau : after I have changed my software to start minimized did this occur . At first I thought it is only Windows 2012 but after I put my Software on a completely different Windows 10 Computer and the same started occurring ... I became suspicions that it is me. What I noticed is once i closed SQL Manager explorer returned to normal , except Total Commander and copy paste. Anyway I have now changed my software to use DevExpress TaskBarProgress . If after a week it is working then it was the combination of OS/SQL Manager/TTaskBar.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : well it works now . Without any problems . But I guess it is almost impossible to answer why the built-in component is causing this.